# chcek valid palindrome(basic) , buffer overflow ,

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am newbie and I have to check valid palindrome string.
Here is my code in c++

```
char to_lower(char ch){
        char c = ch - 'A' + 'a';
        return c;
    }
bool isPalindrome(string s) {
        int l = s.length(); 
        string t = "";
        for(int i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++){
            if(((s[i]>='a' && s[i]<='z') || (s[i]>='A' && s[i]<='Z') || (s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9')))
                t.push_back(s[i]);
                    if(t[i]>='A' && t[i]<='Z')
                       t[i] =  to_lower(t[i]);
            
         }
        int i=0;
        int j=t.length()-1;
        while(i<=j){
            if(t[i]!=t[j])
                return false;
           else
                i++;
                j--;
        }
            return true;
    }
```

It is showing stack buffer overflow. I am not understanding this error is showing. Please help me

Comment: Can you show your `main()` function too? And what have you given as input?

Comment: `else  i++;  j--;` should be `else { i++;  j--; }`, otherwise the `j--;` is unconditional. look at the compiler warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/v89aen8vG

Comment: Actaully I'm solving this question from leetcode so I have not written main() function.